# Replacing Reporting Services with Javascript & WebAPI

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, charts, asp.net-web-api

We are currently replacing a existing Asp.net Application with the main purpose of displaying various Reports of Microsoft Reporting Service.

The new application has a Ext.js (JS Framework) front end and communicates with a .net WebAPI back end.

The reports (charts and also matrices) need to be displayed in the webapp(features like sorting or filtering included) as well to be automatically created and sent out via email.

Displaying the report in the browser is relatively easy and we also have some experience using MigraDoc to create PDF reports.

But are there any solutions out there that doesn't need us to create the same report twice and still gives us all the features we need?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this -

http://blogs.telerik.com/careypayette/posts/13-09-23/bringing-the-power-of-html5-to-telerik-reporting

Telerik reporting has the ability to create reports in a web api project and send that to the browser.